# Python: Memory optimised way of defining matrices in numpy

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, numpy, matrix

```
import numpy as np
```

#### Preface:

*Skip preface if you get bored reading because you know this already.*

I've recently come across a problem while debugging. I wrote `A = B = C = np.zeros([3,3]) and I thought I've just defined three new matrices. What I did was in fact different. I defined one new matrix (filled with zeros) and three labels, each referring to the same matrix. Let me illustrate with the following example:

```
>>> a = b = [0,0]
>>> a
[0,0]
>>> b
[0,0]
>>> # All good so far.
>>> a[0] = 1
>>> a
[1,0]
>>> # Nothing short of what one would expect...
>>> b
[1,0]
>>> # ... but since 'b' is assigned tot he same tuple, it changes as well.
```

#### The question:

Well. Now that I know that's no problem right? Surely I can just write:

```
A = np.zeros([3,3])
B = np.zeros([3,3])
C = np.zeros([3,3])
```

and everything works? That's right but I could equally well write:

```
A, B, C = np.zeros([3,3,3])
```

I would think that the second option uses memory in more efficient way since it defines a 3x3x3 tensor and then 3 labels A, B and C for each of it's layers instead of three separate matrices with possible bits of memory between them.

Which one would you think is better?

Comment: unfortunately this likely will get closed since it is not the right format for SO. ..  but just run timeit and looks at your procmon to see memory and time footprints for both... what people think is totally irrelevant , its easy enough for you to check the metrics yourself

Comment: You normally only do the unpacking thing if you expect to use the 3D array for something (e.g. calculating the element-wise average across all 3 matrices), and that of course requires giving it a label: `big_array = np.zeros((3, 3, 3)); a, b, c = big_array`. It's mostly a matter of personal taste, although if your arrays are very big, it may be easier to find three slots of one third the size, than a single one of the full size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of all, it smells like premature optimization. If we're talking about a small number of matrices, it doesn't matter either way. If we're talkiing about a large number of matrices, you're not likely to make use of unpacking.

Having said that, the second option involves creating a larger underlying storage, while the first one creates three separate storages. The former is somewhat more efficient if all three matrices share the same lifetime. The latter is more readable, and allows releasing memory of individual matrices. If this kind of optimization matters to you at all, measure.

Comment: I'm not sure you understand very well how numpy deals with memory and views... What do you mean by "garbage"? How does such a standard feature like unpacking hurt readability? How do you reckon the former method would be more memory efficient?

Comment: @Jaime You're right, I spoke too soon referring to "garbage". I've now updated the answer to more accurately reflect the tradeoffs involved.

Answer (score 3):

I made a simple test to see what is going on in the two cases (Code and results below). As suspected the latter approach allocates memory linearly while the former is scattering it where ever it is allowed to by the system (which I would have expected to be more tightly than it was).
So the latter is more efficient in terms of memory location. But in terms of allocation time (timing the script below) they are equivalent (the unpacking seems to steal some time and we are talking about almost very small numbers). So thinking about this is most likely premature optimisation.

```
import sys
import numpy as np
nr = 1000
rounds =1000
if len(sys.argv)==2:
    if sys.argv[1]=='seq':
        print "testing sequential allocation"
        for i in xrange(rounds):
            a=np.zeros([nr,nr])
            b=np.zeros([nr,nr])
            c=np.zeros([nr,nr])
    elif sys.argv[1]=='all':
        print "testing allocating all at once"
        for i in xrange(rounds):
            A,B,C=np.zeros([3,nr,nr])
        
        
a=np.zeros([3,3])
b=np.zeros([3,3])
c=np.zeros([3,3])
A,B,C=np.zeros([3,3,3])

print "diff in location b-a", b.__array_interface__['data'][0]-a.__array_interface__['data'][0]
print "diff in location c-a", c.__array_interface__['data'][0]-a.__array_interface__['data'][0]
print "diff in location B-A", B.__array_interface__['data'][0]-A.__array_interface__['data'][0]
print "diff in location C-A", C.__array_interface__['data'][0]-A.__array_interface__['data'][0]
```

OUTPUT

> > diff in location b-a -125520
>
> >diff in location c-a -173376
>
> >diff in location B-A 72
>
> >diff in location C-A 144